# How to prevent unwanted sharing of my Excel Sheets

Tags: excel, security, generics

I am wondering if there is any way of preventing someone from further sharing an Excel Sheet I created.

For example: If I sent the sheet to Person A and don't want A to share it further. (But A should still be able to work with the sheet)

I don't think a password is suitable since Person A knows it and can pass it to B.

Recently I watched a video from the PlainBagel where he delves into NFTs and I am thinking that this could be an option. I don't want to make money from it, rather just preventing unwanted publication.

Do you have any ideas if this is possible at all or if there are other ways to "secure" the Excel Sheet.

Comment: a bit of vba code that gets the computer info the first time its run then check each time it is run subsequently? if it does not match it quits without saving...

Comment: thats an idea, thanks I will try it out